# How to get a nested List item value in a json response blob

Tags: json, rest-assured

I'm using the Rest-Assured framework to read and verify responses from a REST service. I have the following json blob, returned from a POST call, and I need to extract the value for "chatNumber":

```
    {
    "authorized": true,
    "guest": {
        "chatNumber": 371442,
        "username": "billyBob",
        "guestId": 37561,
        "primary": true,
        "coppaRestricted": false
    }
}
```

The json response has been saved to an object called "Response".

I want to do something like:

```
String myValue = Response.path("chatNumber");
```

But it's not working. path() can't find "chatNumber". There's syntax that I'm apparently missing to get the "chatNumber" value from within the "guest" list of items. I'm not sure I'm even using the correct language to describe "guest"...

What must I do to get the value of "chatNumber" from the json blob above?

Any help here would be lifesaving.

Thanks,

Wulf

Answer (score 3):

So, with the help of better Devs than I here at work, this is how to get the value of chatNumber in the above json blob:

Use the following imports:

```
import com.jayway.restassured.RestAssured;
import com.jayway.restassured.response.Response;
import com.jayway.restassured.path.json.JsonPath;
import static com.jayway.restassured.RestAssured.given;
```

With the json response blob listed above (called Response) already being captured after a REST POST call, do this:

```
String myBlob = Response.asString();

int chatNumber = JsonPath.with(myBlob).get("guest.chatNumber");
```

Then if we print the contents of `chatNumber` at runtime like so:

`System.out.println(chatNumber);`

we get:

```
371442
```

Two days of my life spent trying to figure this out. Ugh....

Hopefully someone else gets a little help from my suffering. :-)

Comment: You should have a look at the documentation, it's pretty much the first example. https://github.com/jayway/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#object-mapping

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure this is the correct format:

`String myValue = Response.jsonPath().getString("guest.chartNumber");`